# Google Deployment Manager pass command line parameters to --config files like you can with templates

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/define-template-properties

`--properties` is only supported for Jinja templates:

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments create a-single-vm --template vm_template.jinja \
    --properties zone:us-central1-a
```

How do I pass properties to Python templates the same way with `--config`?

### Edit

More info about my use case. I have a top level yaml `config` that pulls in multiple templates and sets properties. I can just create separate top level configs for dev and prod deployments with diff values for those environments but it would be nice to set these via command line.

Also I may need to dynamically change some of these params at deploy time in my deployment automation- for example when users click a button to deploy they are given the option to set some params to change. Is there any native support for transforming configs? I don't want to have to resort to wrapping my configs with a makefile.

Comment: The flag should work with python as well, the variable in the python script needs to be defined to pull from `context.properties['variable']` and it should work, are you getting an error when you try?

Comment: if i try to use `--config` with `--properties` it tells me `--properties` can only be used against a template

Comment: that's correct. You want to use the `--template` flag and specify your `template.py`. Within the template, there should be variables that use `context.properties['varialble']` so when you do `--properties variable:new-value` the variable in the template will be replaced with new-value

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use python template using multiple templates in Cloud Deployment Manager. Have a look at the [link](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/using-multiple-templates#create_the_configuration) for detail configuration.

Comment: Irrelevant - OP is clearly asking regarding `--config` mode